# Let Apache transform XML with XSLT 2.0 automatically

Tags: apache2, xml

I'm currently trying to host a little project on my Apache web server. For this project we had the instructions to use XSLT and we always used SAXON to transform our XML to HTML, but I really have no clue how I should do this on my web server. Every time I try to open the XML on the web server, it says that it couldn't evaluate an invalid expression which I think is due an XSLT 2.0 function we used.

*Is there a way to upgrade to 2.0 so Apache can transform it?*

Comment: @Anderson: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1056177/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future... **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

If you use the JAXP API for initiating the transformation, then you're very dependent on getting the classpath right, because the system will load whatever XSLT engine it finds first on the classpath.

If your code depends on using an XSLT 2.0 processor then this is unreliable, it's better to load Saxon explicitly rather than relying on the JAXP mechanism. To do this replace `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` in your code by `new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`

Comment: I'm not using the API and we just used Saxon for offline testing. My goal is that you can call the XML file (which is connected to a xsl stylesheet) in the browser and it delivers a HTML back.
e.g. example.org/content.xml which then shows display the HTML generated by the xsl-stylesheet.
Sorry for my bad explanation since I'm a bloody beginner in terms of this.

Comment: OK, so it sounds as if you're running the transformation in the browser, not on the web server as previously suggested. If you want to run XSLT 2.0/3.0 in the browser, you'll need the Saxon-JS product. Note that this will require a little Javascript in the HTML page to invoke the transformation, you can't configure the browser to invoke a different XSLT processor unfortunately, and the native XSLT processors in the browsers are all limited to XSLT 1.0.